# Using Home System for PA Duties

Tags: audio, speakers, live-sound

I have a 150W amp and these two Pioneer speakers (6 ohms, 75W each) that have 8 inch woofers and look pretty powerful. I'm wondering if they can be used for PA duty as well... I have a friend who wants to borrow this for use as a PA system for his outdoor party. The sound does not have to be really loud, but loud enough (these speakers produce 91db at 1W), and the amp will be connected to a mixer that is linked to an XLR mic (for speaking, not singing) and a computer for playing music.

It seems that my system is capable enough... I've pushed it hard at my own home and the sound still appears good. However, I'm not sure what I'll be like outdoors (I dont want to test it in my backyard since its tiny and I dont want any complaints, while my friend has a large lot)

We will rent PA speakers if we have to, but I'm wondering if my system can do the job without any damage to the amp or speakers. Only recorded (not live) music will be played through the speakers, so the dynamic range to not too large. However, I just dont want to toast my system.

P.S. If PA speakers are to be rented, how much power is necessary?

Picture of speakers:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how large the lot is and how loud you want the volume.  It's probably going to be a bit of a trick to get a signal into a consumer amp (I guess maybe a tape out could do it if you have a tape out on the mixer), but the speakers should work as long as you don't exceed their limits.  They may or may not be powerful enough though since outdoors is going to be a lot harder to cover than indoors (also, exposure to the elements may not  be great for the speakers).

I don't think there is really going to be an better bet than trying a dry run.  Be sure to plug in the speakers before turning on the amp and turn on the amp at the lowest level.  Don't push them past the point where you hear distortion and it is unlikely that you will damage them.